# Homebrew install gdb with brewed python

Tags: homebrew

I had brewed version of python 2.7.6 installed on OS X mavericks and now am trying to install gdb with `--with-brewed-python` option.

But I am getting the following error message. Why it is checking python in `/usr/local` instead of `/usr/local/bin`? I think this is why it is failing. Anyone has any idea?

```
brew install gdb --with-brewed-python
==> Downloading http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/gdb/gdb-7.6.2.tar.bz2
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gdb/7.6.2 --with-system-readline --with-python=/usr/local
==> make
checking whether to use python... /usr/local
checking for python2.7... no
configure: error: no usable python found at /usr/local
make[1]: *** [configure-gdb] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2

READ THIS: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting
If reporting this issue please do so at (not Homebrew/homebrew):
```

https://github.com/homebrew/homebrew-dupes/issues

Answer (score 1):

try: brew -v install --with-brewed-python gdb
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes/issues/277

Comment: `--with-brewed-python` is obsolete, the correct switch is now `--with-python`.

Comment: Neither works anymore (Homebrew 2.5.2, macOS Catalina 10.15.1). `brew install gdb` attempts to build python3.8 from source ("cannot be installed as binary package"), but that requires `xcode-select --install` which failed for me because the update server is not reachable?